# How to embed a terminal into the desktop on Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, unity

I'm pretty new on Linux, so sorry if it's dumb, but is there a way to embed the terminal into my desktop? And btw, if the anwser is yes, can I embed another terminal on the side who only shows my current location, like something who always runs `ls`?

Comment: Valkas Ironhorn , what is your main goal ? Do you want to have terminal always open ?

Comment: What about `ls` ? you want to always see contents of your current folder, or just where you are right now ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install guake`

Comment: yes thats it, I want an always opened terminal stick on my desktop, and for the second question, I want to see both, whats in my current folder and where I am right now

Comment: "where you're right now"? Where in what?

Answer (score 3):

Dolphin (KDE's default file manager) integrates a terminal whose current working directory is set to the windows' current working directory:

[image: screenshot]

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dolphin
```

To activate the terminal you'll have to hit <kbd>F4</kbd> in Dolphin after the installation, and it will always be present in any new opened window after that until you hit <kbd>F4</kbd> again.

The only downside is you'll have to install most of KDE itself (around 85 MB in my current Debian installation).

Answer (score 0):

A pretty hefty Python script could probably make that happen and sync your current directory with where you are in the file browser, but a much easier solution would be to install **Guake** or **Yakuake**. They are dropdown terminals, both by default are summoned by pressing F12. I use Yakuake every day wherever I go because I use KDE, but if you use the default Unity desktop or a GNOME variant then install Guake instead.

Answer (score 0):

I created a program called Deskterm that does this for you.
https://github.com/jamrizzi/deskterm